# How to create comma separated list from a while-loop?

Tags: php, csv, while-loop

```php
$personas = [
'Hermann' => [
  'status' => '0',
  'gender' => 'maskulin'
],
'Lida' => [
  'status' => '1',
  'gender' => 'feminin'
],
'Susi' => [
  'status' => '0',
  'gender' => 'feminin'
],
'Mara' => [
  'status' => '0',
  'gender' => 'feminin'
]
];
```

**Personas with status 0**

```php
  echo 'Personas with status 0: ';
  while ($status = current($personas)) {
    if ($status['status'] == '0') {
    $status_list = key($personas);
    echo $status_list;

  }
  next($personas);
}
```

**Result is:**
Personas with status 0: HermannSusiMara

**is expected:**
Personas with status 0: Hermann, Susi, Mara

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit different solution for you.

```
$statusZeroPersonae = [];

foreach($personas as $personaName => $persona) {
    if ($persona['status'] === '0') {
        $statusZeroPersonae[] = $personaName;
    }
}

echo 'Personae with status 0: ' . implode(", ", $statusZeroPersonae);
```

Comment: I made basically the same thing here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/38a226181fd8811b48d88f75e296b62d3ea3ae62

Answer (score 0):

The `implode()` function is quite handy for such things...

I also took the liberty to clean up your code a bit:

```
<?php
$personas = [
  'Hermann' => [
    'status' => '0',
    'gender' => 'maskulin'
  ],
  'Lida' => [
    'status' => '1',
    'gender' => 'feminin'
  ],
  'Susi' => [
    'status' => '0',
    'gender' => 'feminin'
  ],
  'Mara' => [
    'status' => '0',
    'gender' => 'feminin'
  ]
];

echo 'Personas with status 0: ';
while ($status = current($personas)) {
  if ($status['status'] == '0') {
    $personaName = key($personas);
    $personasWithStatus0[] = $personaName;
  }
  next($personas);
}
echo implode(", ", $personasWithStatus0);
```

The output obviously is:

> Personas with status 0: Hermann, Susi, Mara

Answer (score 0):

You can keep them in an array and use `join` or `implode`

```
while ($status = current($personas)) {
  if ($status['status'] == '0') {
   $result[] = key($personas);
 }
 next($personas);
}
echo 'Personas with status 0: '.join(', ',$result);
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/qjgPC